# Function reference on native alert fails with invalid calling object

Tags: javascript, alert, chaining

Consider the following code:

```
function test()
{
   return {
      alert : function(txt){ alert(txt);}
   }
}
test().alert("Boo");
```

This will execute perfectly and alerts `Boo`.

The following will fail:

```
function test()
{
   return {
      alert : window.alert
   }
}
test().alert("Boo");
```

Error `invalid calling object`

Why does the last example fails when referring to window.alert?

Comment: last example fail, because you call it with `invalid calling object` :-) this `window.alert.bind(window)` fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.alert` expects window to be bound to `this`, which is not satisfied when you call it like that. (i.e. `test().alert` will have `this` set as the object returned from `test()`.)

You can fix it like this:

```
return {
  alert : window.alert.bind(window)
}
```

`console.log`, for example, behaves the same way.